# C/C++ embedding python module PIL, the python function want to return all pixel data, but i why can't?

Tags: c++, python, c, python-imaging-library, embedding

add c/c++ code embedding python. all problem is in c code, I don't known how to get the pixel value.

*python code:*

```
import Image

format = ""
mode = ""
size = ""
data = list()

def getImage(file):
    im = Image.open(file)
    global format
    global mode
    global size
    global data
    format = im.format
    mode = im.mode
    size = im.size

    width, height = im.size

    for x in range(0, height):
        for y in range(0, width):
            data.append(im.getpixel((x,y)))
    return None
```

in C/C++ code
My get the data length is 0. Any problems of the two for loop?

```
void loadImage(char *file) {
    Image* img = NULL;
    Py_Initialize();
    if ( !Py_IsInitialized() ) {
        std::cerr<<"Python initalize failed.\n";
        return NULL;
    }
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");

    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs;
    pName = PyString_FromString("loadImage");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    Py_DECREF(pName);
    if ( !pModule ) {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cerr<<"import loadImage module faild, please confirm where the file     'loadImage.py' is.\n";
        return NULL;
    }
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "getImage");
    if ( !pFunc ) {
        PyErr_Print();
        std::cerr<<"Can't find method getImage in loadImage module.\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, Py_BuildValue("s", file));
    PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);

    PyObject *pFormat, *pMode, *pSize, *pData, *pSeq, *pPixel;

    pFormat = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "format"); 

    pMode = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "mode");

    pSize = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "size");

    if ( !PyTuple_Check(pSize) ) {
        std::cerr<<"pSize is not tupple object.\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    pData = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "data");
    if ( !pData ) {
        std::cerr<<"pData is null.\n";
        return NULL;
    }
    if ( !PyList_Check(pData) ) {
        std::cerr<<"pData is not list object.\n";
        return NULL;
    }

    int n = PyList_GET_SIZE(pData);
    std::cerr<<n<<"\n";

    Py_DECREF(pData);
    Py_DECREF(pFunc);
    Py_DECREF(pModule);
    Py_DECREF(pArgs);

    std::cerr<<"Py_DECREF over.\n";
}
```

I get the lenght of pData(is n) is 0.

Comment: You're not calling your function, so `data` is never populated? Also, why in the world would you use a global variable for that?

Comment: oh... I know, this code is moddify many times, the last version is that, but i promise it isn't like that at the original version.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code can literally be replaced with a single line:

```
data = list(Image.open(file).getdata())
```

The `getdata` method of Image objects returns the pixels packed into a list, line-by-line. If you need them in column-major order (as you are doing), apply `.transpose` with the appropriate arguments first. The result will still be substantially faster and simpler than iterating over all the pixels.

Comment: Yeah, I know can code like this, but I found in my c/c++ code 'data' is NULL object, what should i do?

Comment: OK, then you have to show your embedding code. There's nothing wrong on the Python end...

Answer (score 0):

You aren't checking the return value from `PyObject_CallObject`. It might have returned `NULL` (Python exception), and consequently failed to modify the `data` list.

You should check *every* Python API call you make, since exception handling is critically important to making the interpreter work correctly.

If you do get a `NULL`, you can call `PyErr_Print()` to get the traceback printed out to `stderr` (`cerr`).

Comment: I had output the values of format, mode, size, work well, i got their correct value. Only data is error, get the lenght of data is 0. When I set the init value of data = [1, 3, 5, ] in python code, then i can get length of data is 3. I don't know why the pixel value hav't append to data list.

Comment: Well, the function might have thrown an exception *in the loop*...you still need to check its return value! Maybe you should throw some print statements in there to check whether the loop is even being executed at all.

Comment: Your are right. I should check the return value, PyObject_CallObject return me a NULL, so terrible. I also code like this "data = list(im.getdata())". But PyObject_CallObject always return NULL for me.

Comment: oh...no... this function return None is correct. I code return None in python code.

Comment: `NULL` is not the same as `None` in the Python C API. None has a particular non-NULL value since it's a Python object: `Py_None`. If a `PyObject *` function returns `NULL`, it surely encountered an exception: this is the rule of the C API.

Comment: Try using `PyErr_Print` after the function returns NULL to get some information on the exception.

Comment: shit... got this error:  ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed

Answer (score 0):

The Python code you run by calling `PyObject_CallObject` is probably throwing an exception.

NULL means an exception was thrown.  You can use various python api functions to get at 
the actual error: http://docs.python.org/c-api/exceptions.html.  This is probably the simplest.

```
if( PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs ) == NULL )
{
    // Print the exception (a traceback may or may not be available)
    PyErr_Print();

    // Do any cleanup...

    // Always return NULL after a python api function returns NULL.
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: many tks, print this error: ImportError: The _imaging C module is not installed.

Comment: I can't found how to solve this problem. I asked the another question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328895/c-c-embedding-python-error-importerror-the-imaging-c-module-is-not-installe

Answer (score 0):

The problem may caused by the python version 2.7 in my computer. I changed to python 3.2, all code can got ideal return.